# Issue while using bigquery with pyspark-Not working with Dataframe transformation operations such as df.filter : action works such as df.show

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-bigquery, etl, google-cloud-dataproc

[image: Error Snippet :]

Two ways I tried :

1. Working - Create as temptable using createorreplacetempview() , and apply transformation using spark sql , it's working .
2. Not working - Creating as data frame and apply dataframe api for transformation . the below issue snippet has the exception details .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Can you provide the code that's creating this error?

Comment: bucket = "[bucket]"
spark.conf.set('temporaryGcsBucket', bucket)

# Load data from BigQuery. This was quite a huge external table from BQ . 
df= spark.read.format('bigquery') \
  .option('table', '<project><dataset><table name>') \
  .load()    
#df.show() #this line is working . Only the transformations are not .
df.columns # Error line

if i use df.createOrReplacetempview() , operations are working .

Comment: Has the spark-bigquery-connector been installed on your cluster like instructed in this link? https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example

Comment: Yes , I am using the jar during the spark submit as --jar=--jars=gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar

Comment: I mean other operations are working . When i try to perform action like df.count() , df.show() ... they are all working .. when i try to perform transformation such as df.filter .. it throwing this exception ...

Comment: Even for considerably small tables it's (df.filter and df.columns )working .. In my scenario I have to deal with huge external tables .. So that's not helping me ..

Comment: Can you please the table's schema?

Comment: @VenkatKrish Could you add the code in the question? I can help reproduce.